# Quitting a job to work at a better job which I might have to end up quitting anyway

Tags: united-states, quitting, software-development, careers

I recently graduated from college with a CS degree and almost immediatley started working full time at company A.  I had been with this company for several months before I graduated and became aware of extremely poor development practices, a lack of company culture, and an inconvinent commute.  Despite this, at the urging of my family, I accepted the full time offer.  In the meantime I  also applied at a high profile tech company (company B), which by all accounts, seems like it would be *much* better than company A in almost every respect (benefits, location, workplace environment, etc.).

Fast forward to now and I have been working full time at company A for about two weeks, meanwhile the application process is going forward very smoothly for company B and I am fairly certain that I will get an offer.  Although it is a tough decision I know that I should quit company A for company B as soon as I get the offer.

However, all of this is complicated by the fact that my partner has applied for a program that would take her out of the country, and I would be coming with her.  *If* she gets in then we will depart in late July, meaning that I will only be working at company B for about 6 months before having to once again quit.  If my partner is not accepted, then it would be much better for me to be working at company B.

If I do get the job offer at company B, should I take it or would it be better to keep working at company A - I am mainly wondering what will look better on my resume down the road: Two 6 month stretches, the latter one at a high profile company, or one 1 year stretch at an unknown company?

Comment: How is this complicated by your partner's program?  You already have decided that if your girlfriend leaves the country then you will leave too.  Whatever job that you have at that point you will have to quit so you might as well accept B's offer if they present one.

Comment: @sf02 It sounds like they're worried about being labeled as a "job hopper". Quitting one job to move abroad is not the same as quitting one job, only to quit the next one 6 months later to move abroad.

Comment: @quiznars9797 I suspect you're being downvoted because you're currently asking "What should I do?", which is discouraged on this site. 
Maybe you could rework the question to be more general and useful for other people. To me, it sounds like you're asking leaving a second job 6 after months would brand you as a job hopper if your reason was that you're leaving the country. Is that it?

Comment: @Llewellyn That is true, but OP was working with A before he graduated.  It's fairly normal for someone to quit whatever job they have for a better one shortly after graduation.

Answer (score 7):

There's a lot of "ifs" in your future.  There's a limit to how much looking ahead into the future we can do.

I suggest you make the best move you can with the information that's available to you right now, and that means accepting company "B"'s offer if they make it.

If your partner's career takes you somewhere else, then deal with that when it happens.